# links working in Mozilla Firefox, but not in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, codeigniter, internet-explorer

I seem to have problems with my links, they are not doing anything in Internet Explorer

```
<a style="text-decoration:none;" href="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/person/create/<?php echo $this->uri->segment(4);?>" >
```

If I look at the source my link is `href="http://localhost/index.php/person/create/2"`.
This is working in Mozilla but in IE the link is going nowhere.

Comment: that's pretty basic stuff. I seriously doubt that IE is failing to handle a simple `<a>` tag. that said, you haven't shown us the rest of the code: ie the bit the user actually clicks on; there could be an error there too. Have you run your HTML code through the W3C validator to see if there are any validation errors that might break things? Also, have you tried putting the URL directly into IE's address bar? Does that work? It could be a problem with the URL rather than the link.

Comment: index.php/person/create/2 ? Is that the correct link? First thoughts are because you have index.php then slash after it. If you want to pass parameters to the index page you should be using GET headers or sessions.

Comment: By the way, when asking IE questions, please always specify the IE version you're testing with. I may not make a difference in this case, but it very often does, so it's important to include it.

Comment: @Jason It belongs to CI framework.

Comment: yes that is the correct link if i type the address directly onto the address bar its working and in mozilla firefox its working

Comment: @janson  i have sessions and they are working "2" in this case is the id of user logged in picked was picked up by the "view source"

Comment: Can you increase the code in the question so it includes all the HTML from the start of the `<a>` tag right through to the closing `</a>`?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you didn't mean to put `index.php` in your url - I doubt that you can traverse into `/person/create/2` after `index.php`. Try removing that?

Comment: index.php has to there because i'm using codeigniter framework, i did not go for the htaccess option

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php $url = $this->uri->segment(4); ?>
<a style="text-decoration:none;" href="<?php echo base_url("index.php/person/create/$url");?>">click</a>
```

If you have an index page specified in your 'config.php' you don't have to add /index.php/ to your url.

Hope it helps.

Comment: It doesn't make any sense. What is the difference?

Comment: Do you have an index page specified? if so, remove index.php from your url.

Comment: It should work in both situation, whether the `/index.php/` is used or not.

Comment: But if you click the link it redirects? or it does nothing?

Comment: It doesn't redirect. It works because this is the native PHP way for routing. However I'm not the OP. Hope it makes sense for him/her.

Comment: Oh did not notice you weren't the OP. nevermind.. This is a strange problem, because he/she noticed that it works in other browsers. CI has a lot of problems with IE. :(

Comment: @KeesSonnema if i click on the link nothing happens but on the address bar if i type directly the address line represented by that link it works perfectly

Comment: Check if you have a slash '/' after your base_url in your config file. If you haven't add one. then try again.